# Pythonic Way to Split A String Based On SubString

Tags: python-3.x, string

I'm working with college basketball data. The two fields I have right now are the raw matchup and the predicted winner.

| RawMatchup | PredictedWinner |
| --- | --- |
| MinnesotaLouisville | Louisville |

I want to use the Predicted Winner to separate out the two teams in the RawMatchup column. Currently I'm using replace to remove the Predicted Winner from the RawMatchup.

```
RawMatchup.replace(PredictedWinner, '')
>>Minnesota
```

This works for the vast majority of the rows in my dataset. The problem I'm having is when both school's partially share a name

| RawMatchup | PredictedWinner |
| --- | --- |
| GeorgiaGeorgia Tech | Georgia |
| North Carolina CentralNorth Carolina | North Carolina |

Using split for these two rows returns just 'Tech' and 'Central' (instead 'Georgia Tech' and 'North Carolina Central'). How can I best separate the Predicted Winner from the Raw Matchup while preserving the correct school names?

Comment: What would you want them to return, and by what logic do you arrive at that decision?

Comment: The raw matchup feels kinda odd. It's actually storing two fields in one field. You'd expect at least a semicolon, slash, or some other delimiter between the two. If you can't control how the RawMatchup is generated, then the most vivid pattern I see is to split the RawMatchup manually (i.e. with a loop) by looking for adjacent lower-case and upper-case letters (e.g. GeorgiaGeorgia –> Georgia Georgia; CentralNorth –> Central North). Once you've performed that cutoff, it becomes clear which one to remove.

Comment: Yeah the RawMatchup is just part of the files I'm working with - I didn't generate it on my own. PredictedWinner was basically the same - one field that stored about 5 different values. Luckily that one was easy enough to split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `split` because IMO it's intended for a different purpose (usually splitting the elements by standard separators such as commas, or whitespaces). In this case, what you want is removing `PredictedWinner` from `RawMatchup` *only once*. Therefore I'd go for `replace` and `sub` to achieve the goal.

It seems that `PredictedWinner` is either at the end or at the beginning of `RawMatchup`. We could take advantage of that to define the following function:

```py
import re

def remove_winner_from_raw(raw_matchup, predicted_winner):
    if (raw_matchup.endswith(predicted_winner)):
        res = re.sub(f"{predicted_winner}$", '', raw_matchup) # regexp
    else:
        res = raw_matchup.replace(predicted_winner, '', 1) # Just the 1st occurrence
    return res

print(remove_winner_from_raw("North Carolina CentralNorth Carolina", "North Carolina"))
# Output: North Carolina Central

print(remove_winner_from_raw("GeorgiaGeorgia Tech", "Georgia"))
# Output: Georgia Tech
```

Docs for:

- `str.replace`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html
- `re.sub`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html